# How can I generate a custom SOAP message

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-serialization, messagecontract

I have a site that give me this xml response on my GET request:

```
<ServerUnits>
    <State Name="ServerName" Date="2008-04-01" >
    <Users>
       <User login="someUser1" Password="123456">
       <User login="someUser2" Password="qwerty">
    </Users>
</ServerUnits>
```

I want use WCF Client for work with this service.
How to discraibe Message Contract of this response for WCF Clien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to create client proxies for the WCF service. It will create the data contracts for you (as mentioned by @Aliostad) so you don't have to create them manually. To do this right click on your solution and select "Add Service Reference..." from the context-menu and enter the address to your WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

What you have posted is not a SOAP message so `MessageContract` is not appropriate.

I imagine what you posted is the SOAP body content so you need to do something along the line of this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServerUnits
{
    [DataMember]
    public ServerState State { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ServerState
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string login { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }

}
```

---

### UPDATE

Your message is not SOAP. But you can still use the code above if you use `webHttpBinding` which sends and receives POX.

Comment: This is full response from service
And therefore I can not use DataContract

Answer (score 0):

I think that WCF is not useful is your case.

A more simple way would be to write objects that match this xml response and just deserialize xml stream onto objects instances.